# Find a median in parallel

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

If you have one huge amount of numbers and one hundred computers,
How would you find the median of the numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use selection algorithm.

1. Split the array of number to 100 partitions.
2. Each processor should use the general pivot to split the array to two groups (left/right)
3. Then each processor should send the size of those 2 groups to the leader
4. The leader should calculate which group is smaller and broadcast a message to get rid of one of those groups.
5. Go back to step 2 until you find the median

this solution has an avg runtime of O(n)
in order to make it asymptotic runtime of O(n), each processor should split the numbers to groups of 5 elements find the median of each group
(using insertion sort) and send those medians back to the leader, the leader will choose the median of those medians (using the same algorithm) and that
will be the pivot

read the wiki article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: +1, but I think you meant to say ["selection algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), not selection sort.

Comment: @MrOhad, I don't get it. The leader calculate which group is smaller and broadcast a message to get rid from one of those groups? Why?

Comment: Can anyone clarify this answer? Especially step 4? Does ONE item get removed from each of the 100 partitions? Or do one HALF of the items get removed?

Comment: @Hardbyte: The leader chooses a pivot and all processors return the number of elements they have left and right of the pivot.  The leader decides which group to discard (the smaller of the two), and counts the number of elements being discarded.  The pivot is increased (decreased) if the left (right) is discarded.  Again, the processor gets the count of left vs. right, but keeps the number of previously discarded elements in its count.  The pivot is adjusted until one element remains (or two, if an even number of elements, returning the mean of the two) or all remaining elements are the same.

Comment: this sounds great, is there some example code available?